# Problem using jquery ui combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a jquery combobox. When user selects an product it redirects user to product info page. Unfortunately it does not work as expected. I used a normal select it works great.

```
    (function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            var input = $( "<input>" )
                .insertAfter( select )
                .val( value )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                                            "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                                            $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                                            ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                                        ), "<strong>$1</strong>" ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option  
                        });
                    },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ),
                                valid = false;
                            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                if ( this.value.match( matcher ) ) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;                                                                               
                                }
                            });
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $( this ).val( "" );
                                select.val( "" );
                                return false;
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                })
                .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" );

            input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul );
            };

            $( "<button>&nbsp;</button>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .insertAfter( input )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        input.autocomplete( "close" );
                        return;
                    }

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    input.focus();
                });
        }
    });
})( jQuery );

$(function() {
    $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
});
</script>
```

I have using change event, it does not work.

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#combobox").change(function() {
            location.href = $(this).val();
        });
    });
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple. This worked for me.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Insert between `<head>` and `</head>` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-combobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">        
    $('selector').combobox();    
    $('selector').change(function(){ ... });
</script>
```

Code "jquery-ui-combobox.js":

```
$.widget( "ui.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            var self = this,
                select = this.element.hide(),
                selected = select.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";
            var input = this.input = $( "<input />" )
                .insertAfter( select )
                .val( value )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                        var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
                        response( select.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                            var text = $( this ).text();
                            if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                                return {
                                    label: text.replace(
                                        new RegExp(
                    "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)",
                    "gi"
                  ),
                  "<strong>$1</strong>"
                ),
                                    value: text,
                                    option: this
                                };
                        }) );
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        ui.item.option.selected = true;
                        self._trigger( "selected", event, {
                            item: ui.item.option
                        });
          $(select).change(); //Change COMBOBOX
        },
                    change: function( event, ui ) {
                        if ( !ui.item ) {
                            var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( $(this).val() ) + "$", "i" ), valid = false;
                            select.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                                if ( $( this ).text().match( matcher ) ) {
                                    this.selected = valid = true;
                                    return false;
                                }
                            });
                            if ( !valid ) {
                                // remove invalid value, as it didn't match anything
                                $( this ).val( "" );
                                select.val( "" );
                                input.data( "autocomplete" ).term = "";
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addClass( "ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" )
      .css('margin', '0')
      .css('padding', '0.48em 0 0.47em 0.45em');

            input.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                return $( "<li></li>" )
                    .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                    .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                    .appendTo( ul )
        .css('cursor', 'pointer');
            };

    this.button = $( "<button>&nbsp;</button>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .insertAfter( input )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
      .addClass( "ui-corner-right ui-button-icon" )
      .css('margin-left','-1')
      .css('padding','0.15em')
                .click(function() {
                    // close if already visible
                    if ( input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" ) ) {
                        input.autocomplete( "close" );
                        return;
                    }

                    // pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                    input.focus();

        $(select).click(); //Click COMBOBOX
      });
        },

        destroy: function() {
            this.input.remove();
            this.button.remove();
            this.element.show();
            $.Widget.prototype.destroy.call( this );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can directly specify in the following event like:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
    ui.item.option.selected = true;
    location.href = select.val();
    self._trigger( "selected", event, {
        item: ui.item.option
    });
}
```